# All open coverage, admits an enumerable sub-coverage

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Prove that if $X \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$, then all open coverage of $X$, admits an enumerable sub-coverage.

If {$C_{n}$} $_{n \in I}$ is a cover of $X$, we say that it is open, if $C_{n}$ is open for all $n \in I$.

If {$C_{n}$} $_{n \in I}$ is a coverage of $X$, we say that the coverage is enumerable, if $I$ is enumerable.

Comment: HINT: Use the fact that $\Bbb R^n$ is second countable (i.e., has a countable base).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how would that be?

Comment: Are you asking why $\Bbb R^n$ is second countable, or how that fact can be used?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott wonder how you can use this fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a countable base for $\Bbb R^n$. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be any relatively open cover of $X$. For each $x\in X$ there are a $U_x\in\mathscr{U}$ and a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\cap X\subseteq U_x$. Let $\mathscr{B}_X=\{B_x:x\in X\}$. $\mathscr{B}_X\subseteq\mathscr{B}$, so $\mathscr{B}_X$ is countable, and clearly $X\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr{B}_X$. For each $B\in\mathscr{B}_X$ there is a $U_B\in\mathscr{U}$ such that $B\cap X\subseteq U_B$; why? What can you say about $\{U_B:B\in\mathscr{B}_X\}$?

Comment: Can it then be said that {$U_{B}: B \in \mathscr{B_{X}}$} is an enumerable subcoverage for each open?

Comment: @holiswis: Simpler than that: it’s a countable relatively open subcover of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb R^n$ is second countable:  just consider the open balls with rational radii and centered at points with rational coordinates.  These form a basis for the standard topology.

It now follows easily that $\Bbb R^n$ has the Lindelof property (which is another name for the property you are referring to).